# subtract 1 month interval from date?

Tags: postgresql-11

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH
                        FROM '{{ date.start }}'::timestamp ),'/',
                       EXTRACT(YEAR
                        FROM '{{ date.start }}'::timestamp )) - interval '1' MONTH
```

I get an error when I run this query

> Error running query: operator does not exist: text - interval LINE 25: ... FROM '2019-01-01'::timestamp )) - interval... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `concat()` as it turns the timstamp into a varchar.

If you want to get the start of the month of the "timestamp" value, there are easier way to do that:

```
date_trunc('month', '{{ date.start }}'::timestamp)
```

The result of that is a timestamp from which you can subtract the interval:

```
date_trunc('month', '{{ date.start }}'::timestamp) - interval '1 month'
```

The following sample query:

```sql
with sample_data (input_date) as (
  values 
    (timestamp '2019-01-01 17:18:19'), 
    (timestamp '2019-02-07 16:30:40'), 
    (timestamp '2019-03-02 23:30:42')
)    
select input_date, 
       (date_trunc('month', input_date) - interval '1 month')::date as previous_month_start
from sample_data;
```

returns the following result:

```
input_date          | previous_month_start
--------------------+---------------------
2019-01-01 17:18:19 | 2018-12-01          
2019-02-07 16:30:40 | 2019-01-01          
2019-03-02 23:30:42 | 2019-02-01
```

If you want to *display* the result of that in a different format, apply `to_char()` on the result:

```
to_char(date_trunc('month', input_date) - interval '1 month', 'mm/yyyy')
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=495bb830778f44a4f6534d6846766e9f)

Comment: what if my date is 1/1/2019
then i need when i subtract 1 month get 12/2018 i need to handle this case

Comment: That will work for 2019-01-01 just as well. https://rextester.com/PDFL53085

Comment: The use `MM/YY` as the format string for `to_char()`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and the query in OP I think you are trying to convert a timestamp to customized format of **`MM/YYYY`** minus the 1 month interval.

Following is just one of few approaches to achieve that: Using [**concatenation operator ||**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT (extract(month FROM (input_date - interval '1 month')))::text 
                  || '/' 
                  || (extract(year FROM (input_date - interval '1 month')))::text 
    AS formatted_string;
```